# Ubuntu не видит разделы

Tags: ubuntu

Пытаюсь поставить на ноут 12.04, не видит разметку веника, раньше этот же образ на этот же ноут ставил без проблем, сейчас если выбрать другой вариант, предлагает создать новую таблицу, кто может подсказать, в чём причина? (не в кривости рук!!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запороли таблицу разделов, лично я запорол при помощи Acronis. Так что была точна такая же проблема, и как понял: она решается только создание разделов с нуля (я использовал LiveCD и разбивал при помощи GParted), правда пришлось долго возиться с копированием своих данных, чтобы их не потерять.

Comment: уже понял, переформатировал разделы, созданные после успешной установки ubuntu и удаления(дело было в них), делал с помощью diskmgmt.msc в семёрке, хорошо разделы были небольшие, терять было нечего)